# How to customize the KendoUI panelbar in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid, kendo-panelbar

I am working with Kendo panelbar in angular. I want to customize the panelbar so that it doesn't collapse when I click on the panelbar except for the down arrow icon. Could you please help me with that?

```
 <div class="panelbar-wrapper">
    <kendo-panelbar>
        <kendo-panelbar-item title="PanelBar" expanded="true">
            <ng-template kendoPanelBarContent>
                <span>Item1</span>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-panelbar-item>
    </kendo-panelbar>
</div>
```

[The Ui looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBqA9.png)

you can try the code here as well:
[try code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utxrcj?file=app/app.component.ts)
Thank you everyone